# User object is returning undefined when trying to assign one of its attributes to a new variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose, postman

I'm trying out this code to create a simple order and then when trying to assign the user.shoppingCart Array to a new variable ("products") it says the user is undefined but for example the address is working just fine and then trying to console.log the user.address and user.shoppingCart it actually prints the correct values. Any ideas?

```
exports.createOrder = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);

    if (user.shoppingCart.length < 1) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 'fail',
        message: 'Please first add a product to your shopping cart.',
      });
    }
    const address = req.body.address || user.address;
    const products = user.shoppingCart;
    const total = await getTotal();
    const { paymentMethod } = req.body;

    const order = await Order.create({
      address,
      user: user._id,
      products,
      total,
      paymentMethod,
    });

    res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        order,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: 'fail',
      message: err.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Is req.user coming from another middleware?

Comment: yes it is, but its returning the whole user object as its intended, the problem is when trying to set the shoppingCart to another variable

Comment: the user variable looks good to me, assuming you're getting the user each time. 
you're already accessing the user.shoppingCart in the if condition and if this is working then maybe you're getting errors from somewhere else. can you also add the error from the log you're getting in your question